# Extjs Locked Grid Mouse wheel scrolling issue

Tags: extjs, scroll, extjs-grid

Can anyone help why mouse wheel scrolling very slow in both Firefox and Chrome.
In Internet Explorer its working fine

[Sample Test Case](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/extjs-build/examples/grid/locking-grid.html)

Answer (score 3):

onLockedViewScroll : Ext.emptyFn add this grid config

Comment: I was having the same issue. your answer works for me!